# Analytic continuation of function with $f(2z) = f(z) +1$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

Let $D = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} ~|~ \text{Re}(z) > 1\}$ and $f : D \to \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function such that $f(2z) = f(z) + 1$ for every $z \in D$. I now have to prove that $f$ has a analytic continuation on the right half-plane.

We know that $g: A \to \mathbb{C} : z \mapsto f(z) + 1$ is a holomorphic function where $A = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} ~|~ \text{Re}(z) > 2\}$.

So $g(z) - 1 = f(z)$ for all $z \in A$ and it then follows that $f(z)$ is an analytic continuation of $g(z)$ on $D$. But this would mean that $f(z)$ has an analytical continuation on $B =\{ z \in \mathbb{C} ~|~ \text{Re}(z) > 1/2 \}$.

But now I don't know how I can continue (or if this reasoning is correct). Can I just assume that $f(2z) = f(z) + 1$ also holds on $B$ and use the same argument over and over?

There is also an additional question where I have to show that $f$ has no analytic continuation on a set that contains zero but I have no idea how I can prove that either.

Comment: Use $f(z):=f(2z)-1$. $f$ cannot exist at zero, otherwise $f(0)=f(0)+1$.

Comment: If $f$ can be extended analytically to $0$ then $f(0)=\lim_{z\to0} f(z)=\lim_{z\to0} (f(2z)-1)=f(0)-1$, a contradiction.

Comment: Hint: First show there is a continuation to $\{z:\Re z>1/2\}$. Then continue that continuation to $\{\Re z>1/4\}$...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich that's what I noted in my post so is my reasoning correct or do I need to do something else?

Comment: I don't see where you "noted" that - what I see is "But now I don't know how I can continue (or if this reasoning is correct). Can I just assume that $f(2z)=f(z)+1$ also holds on $B$ and use the same argument over and over?". You didn't specify what you mean by over and over. (Hint about the identityy on $B$: $B$ is connected, and the set where $f(2z)=f(z)-1=0$ has a limit point in $B$.)